# MySQL Replication with tablet

Tags: mysql, replication

Can anyone recommend an app that can replicate a mySQL database running on an android tablet (slave) and on my external web server (master)

Comment: Have you done some research in this matter before posting answer?

Comment: Why do you want to backup the slave? backup the master.

Answer (score 0):

[SymmetricDS](http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview) is capable of synchronizing MySQL databases.  It also support SQL Lite databases on Android depending on your setup.

[Android Blog 1](http://www.jumpmind.com/blog/synchronizing-android-applications-part1)